# Are open-ended contest type questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Are open-ended contest type questions off-topic?

What I am talking about is questions such as:

> Who can create the most [adjective] [type-of-puzzle]?

For example,

> I recently tried to create a nonspecific short line maze [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/a-code-from-the-lines). Are there any other user-created maze types? Post them down below: the highest voted answer at the end of 3 weeks gets the answer reputation.

Are open-ended contest type questions off-topic? Should there be another tag if they are not?

Comment: Is there an existing example?

Comment: @xnor I'm quite sure there is not.

Comment: [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire) question is based on a similar idea, but not quite the same.